# VPN connection on Google Compute Engine

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a new Google Cloud Platform setup. It consists of one VM (more to be added) and a VPN into another network where I have 3 small subnets (two /24 and one /32).

When I first setup the VPN, I just used the /32 and everything was fine - Google VPN connection would establish the connection, from my VM I could ping the /32 IP and everything was great.

This week we tried to bring in the /24's into the connection. I went back into the Google VPN connection, added the /24's in the Remote network IP range and this is where everything started going wrong.

The Google logs show the link is trying to establish, but the only way I can bring up the tunnel is to have someone in the peer network ping my VM, the VPN connection shows ESTABLISHED and for the subnet that peer box is then available from my VM - the other subnets though are still unavailable.

Sometimes I have noticed that if I ping from the peer network in one of the other subnets that subnet will become available and the first will drop (this doesn't always happen and sometimes the peer to VM ping still fails).

Tonight, I have set from the VM two pings towards IP's in the different /24 peer subnets. I can see the connectivity flip flopping between the /24's. Its not toggling quickly (I see that subnet A was working until ping seq 240, stalled until seq 3370 and that carried on working until seq 3660). I hadn't setup iTerm to allow unlimited scrollback so I cant see the stability for subnet B, but from the fact that subnet B has gone past 1000 lines I'd assume that its been up for longer than subnet A.

Both ends of the VPN have been rebuilt a couple of times now and each time the same issue remains. Am I missing some step here, or is there a genuine issue that needs resolving?

If I rebuild the VPN and just allow one of the /24's the issue goes away and things start working again.

Comment: As an update, the peer hardware is a Cisco ISR 3925. As a workaround, I have created two endpoints for the VPN in the Google Cloud Platform with seperate IP's, and they both point towards the same peer IP. Both tunnels came up like that, but this costs me more money as I have to operate two VPN's & 2 Public Static IP's.

Comment: One thing to check in your VPN gateway setting is to see if your gateway is establishing one SA for each subnet, if that's the case it will cause the VPN connectivity issue because Google Cloud VPN creates one SA for all the subnets.

Comment: were you able to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running into an issue outlined in the [vpn documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced#security_associations_and_multiple_subnets):

Security associations and multiple subnets

Cloud VPN creates a single child security association (SA) announcing all CIDR blocks associated with the tunnel. Some IKEv2 peer devices support this behavior, and some only support creating a unique child SA for each CIDR block. With these latter devices, tunnels with multiple CIDR blocks can fail to establish.

There are several workarounds for this issue:

1. Use Cloud Router to create BGP-negotiated routes. With this configuration, the CIDRs are not negotiated in the IKE protocol.
2. Configure the peer device to have several CIDRs in the same child SA. Only some devices support this, and it is only possible in IKEv2.
3. If possible, aggregate the CIDRs into a single, larger CIDR.
4. Create a separate tunnel for each CIDR block. If necessary, you can create several VPN gateways for this purpose.

I ran into the same issue pretty recently trying to connect to a peer with 2 single /32 IP addresses for the remote network. I was able merge the 2 IPs into a single /31 CIDR block and that worked.

That being said, with two /24s and one /32 I don't know if merging them into a single CIDR block is realistic.  You're already doing option 4 as a workaround. If you're using IKEv1, barring anything with Cloud Router (which just recently went from Alpha to Beta) this might be as good as you can do for now.