# Google cloud site to site VPN between VLANs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using a meraki MX100 firewall appliance and couple of VLANs. I setup Google Cloud VPN to work with my network but I realized that although I gave Google all my subnet only the primary VLAN is able to communicate with Google's VPN. If I remote the route for my default VLAN, my next VLAN is able to communicate with Google's VPN. Basically only one VLAN is able to talk with Google at a time. Is there something I am missing? I want all my VLANs to be able to talk to Google's VPN. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that you face thus issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/701694/vpn-connection-on-google-compute-engine/782810

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue going through the serverfault thread provided by Avinoam? If yes, can you post the solution as an answer so that other users with the similar issue can benefit from it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're experiencing security associations issue described in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced#security_associations_and_multiple_subnets):

> Cloud VPN creates a single child security association (SA) announcing
>   all CIDR blocks associated with the tunnel. Some IKEv2 peer devices
>   support this behavior, and some only support creating a unique child
>   SA for each CIDR block. With these latter devices, tunnels with
>   multiple CIDR blocks can fail to establish.
>
> **There are several workarounds for this issue**:
>
> 1. Use Cloud Router to create BGP-negotiated routes. With this
>      configuration, the CIDRs are not negotiated in the IKE protocol.
> 2. Configure the peer device to have several CIDRs in the same child SA.
>      Only some devices support this, and it is only possible in IKEv2.
> 3. If possible, aggregate the CIDRs into a single, larger CIDR.
> 4. Create a
>      separate tunnel for each CIDR block. If necessary, you can create
>      several VPN gateways for this purpose.
>
> All subnets connected to the
>   same tunnel must use the same child SA. If different subnets do not
>   have the same SA, they must be connected to different tunnels.